# How to determine origin of generic arguments in nested types?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Assume the following classes:

```
public class Class1<T>
{
    public class Class2<U>
    {
    }
}
```

When I retrieve the `Type` instance of `Class2<>` to reflect on it, I seem to have a hard time finding out that only generic argument `U` is declared on `Class2`, while `T` originates from the enclosing `Class1`.

I am calling `GetGenericArguments()` to get all the generic arguments for `Class2`, and the result is an array with two elements, `T` and `U`. How can I find out that `T` is declared on `Class1`? `DeclaringType` of *both* arguments returns `Class2`. Is there any other way, beside sifting through the nesting tree and cancelling out any arguments that I encounter on an enclosing class?

Comment: Yeah, in practice, the actual IL implementation of the nested type does in fact replicate the types of the enclosing class, since the idea of the enclosing type's generic parameters falling into the nested type is more C# syntactic sugar than anything else.  I think your workaround is probably your best bet, but be careful in case someone unwisely declares a nested type with a generic parameter with the same name as in the enclosing type.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - that you're being realistic with the sifting idea. I know you've got a good reason for wanting to do this, but I'm real curious. Would you be willing to share why?

Comment: @IVSoftware: I'm trying to generate the IDs found in documentation Xml files output by the C# compiler, so I can match up documentation Xml with the respective `Type` and `MemberInfo` at runtime. The ID for `Class2` above would be `T:Class1`1.Class2`1`, for instance. And once a concrete type is constructed from `Class2` and appears in a method signature, it could look something like this: `Class1{System.Int32}.Class2{System.String}`. Therefore, it is relevant for me to know which generic parameter originates where.